# C# use Ctrl + K + D made the page layout messed up

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I use visual studio to create a new page (as named A.aspx) with c#.
.the page layout looks ok before use `ctrl + D+K` to format .

when I format with `ctrl + K +D`, the page layout then messed up.
I know the `ctrl+ K +D` just adjust the code format ,

the format just look well.

```
   <td align="right" background="images/p3_t_bg.gif" style="height: 24px" valign="top"
                            width="14">
                            <img height="24" src="images/p3_rt_curve.gif" width="14" /></td>
```

after ctrl+K+D

```
   <td align="right" background="images/p3_t_bg.gif" style="height: 24px" valign="top"
                            width="14">
                            <img height="24" src="images/p3_rt_curve.gif" width="14" /></td> // let </td>another line
```

I use table to layout.

I am curious why the formatting will affect the page layout??

**I find that if  is a new line ,then page is messed.**

Can somebody help with this?

Comment: Can you show example of '*messed up*' layout before and after format?

Comment: Try `ctrl+z`...

Comment: What do you mean my messed up?

Comment: I know use ctrl+ z is to Reduction. but I want to well-formatting the code, use ctrl + K +D .

Comment: @chengdu.jack - there must be something else changing - the closing `td` tag on another line makes no difference to the page layout in your browser

Comment: But the page don't have any noted code , how can that be ?

Comment: I find that<td><img ....></td> caused ,the </td> must closed to<img ../></td>  don't have any space.

Answer (score 6):

Check Scott Guthrie aritcle about custom formatting HTML in Visual studio:

[Tip/Trick: Custom formatting HTML in Visual Web Developer and Visual Studio 2005](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/07/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Custom-formatting-HTML-in-Visual-Web-Developer-and-Visual-Studio-2005.aspx)

You can change formatting settings for each tag separetely:

[image]

Comment: I am curious that the formatting will affect the page layout?